# How to hide files in a directory?

Tags: image, hide

[Screenshot of the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIOQi.png)

In this picture, I am trying to hide the files in this picture, but failed. How to do it?

And how to open an hidden file?

Comment: Q: Are you asking "How do I do [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)?"

Comment: "but failed?" how did you fail? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can hide a folder/file by modifying the properties:

[image]

If you want to access the file/folder afterwards, you need to change your view settings to show the hidden files/folders or you need to reference the file/folder by the full pathname in your explorer:

[image: in the windows explorer address bar]